# %d pointer-to-integer conversion in C strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers, integer

By having a look at this code sample:

```
/* strrchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  pch=strrchr(str,'s');
  printf ("Last occurence of 's' found at %d \n",pch-str+1);
  printf("pch number: %d \n str number: %d", pch, str);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
Last occurence of 's' found at 18 
pch number: -8575 
str number: -8592
```

I don't understand, what numbers `pch` and `str` have and what conversion appears to be under `%d` in `printf()`. Is this something like *the number of the memory cell*, where the pointer to the first character lies (in case of `str`)? If so, why `str` is bigger than `pch`? It should represent the pointer to the first string character, shouldn't it? And, finally, why do we need `+1` in `pch-str+1`?

**Addition**: this is not my code (except second `printf()`). I found it on [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com), looking for `strrchr()` reference.

Comment: Always heed the compiler warnings. `pch` and `str` are pointers. Use `%p` to format pointers. And `str` pointer value is *not* larger than `pch`. It's "more negative" and hence a smaller value.

Comment: "And, finally, why do we need +1 in pch-str+1?"  - You don't need it. Try with and without it and observe the differences.

Comment: If any of the answer suit you, you might want to upvote them. You should also accept the answer that covers you the most (press that green tick on the left of the answer - you can only accept one answer).

Comment: "Is this something like the number of the memory cell, where the pointer to the first character lies (in case of str)? If so, why str is bigger than pch?" --> is like asking why your home address is greater than your friend's home address even though you live on the same street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` and `pch` do not store values on their own; They *point* to somewhere in the memory, so their values are actually the address in the memory where they point to.

> **In computer science, a pointer is a programming language object, whose value refers to (or "points to") another value stored elsewhere in the computer memory using its address.** A pointer references a location in memory, and obtaining the value stored at that location is known as dereferencing the pointer. As an analogy, a page number in a book's index could be considered a pointer to the corresponding page; dereferencing such a pointer would be done by flipping to the page with the given page number.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29)

**The results are absolutely natural:** to test this, you must understand how 2's complement work: let's take this example provided by wikipedia:

```
Binary Unsigned 2's complement
011     3       3 
010     2       2 
001     1       1 
000     0       0 
111     7       -1 
110     6       -2 
101     5       -3 
100     4       -4
```

**What I want to show you by this, is that the biggest unsigned binary value gets mapped to the biggest negative value in 2's complement.**

To fix this, change your program as follows:

```
/* strrchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  pch=strrchr(str,'s');
  printf ("Last occurence of 's' found at %ld \n",pch-str+1);
  printf("pch number: %ld \n str number: %ld", pch, str);
  return 0;
}
```

The only change you have to do, is to change `%d` to `%ld`, so, instead of `int` values, the program will print `long int` values.

When I test this piece of code I get:

```
Last occurence of 's' found at 18 
pch number: 140735717807905 
str number: 140735717807888
```

**However, the most typical and correct way to print pointer is by using %p.**

```
/* strrchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  pch=strrchr(str,'s');
  printf ("Last occurence of 's' found at %p \n",pch-str+1);
  printf("pch number: %p \n str number: %p", pch, str);
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
Last occurence of 's' found at 0x12 
pch number: 0x7fffdcf2b3f1 
str number: 0x7fffdcf2b3e0
```

To answer your last question:

> And, finally, why do we need +1 in pch-str+1?

let's see an example:

```
strings
1-----7
```

So let's assume that pch is equal to 7 and str is equal to 1. `pch - str` would yield 6 as a result, so we need to increment that value to show the position of the last `s`.

Comment: this doesnt explain the fact that pch and str are pointers; just the fact that are bigger than ints

Comment: Thank you for a long answer, also going to read more on two's complement.

Answer (score 2):

pch and str are pointers. They contain the address in memory of your string and the last s character. (thats why they differ by 18)

You have not correctly printed them so you have not seen the whole address. Do %p instead of %d (telling the compiler that these are pointers)

pch - str + 1 works because you can add and subtract addresses. They are just very large numbers, but when you subract them you can get small numbers (100001 - 100000 = 1). The compiler knows they are pointers so 'does the right thing'. Why didnt printf 'do the right thing'?, because the way printf works is that the %d is used when the program is running, the compiler doesn't know whats going on. Actually thats a lie,  most modern compilers know the printf behavior and will peek at the format string to see if its OK. If you set you compiler options right it will warn you about doing %d on pointers

Comment: I have a general knowledge about pointers (at least I think so). I understood my mistake trying print them in `%d`. So, the line with `pch-str+1` is still unreachable for my mind. Is it something like pointer arithmetic (judging by another answer) and that conversion to decimal notation? Why, still, `str` points to the end and why do I need to use `+1`? Of course, to make it right, but why? Does `str` point one (what? byte? char? null?) further than a valid string character (seems to be `'\0`?)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes undefined behaviour. The `printf` function isn't "magic": it doesn't know what the types of the arguments are that you pass in. The onus is on you to give the correct format specifiers, then the `printf` function will know where in memory to look and how many bytes to read to get a value for that format.

If you do a mismatch then anything can happen, the function reads the wrong area and you get garbage which may be completely unrelated to the value you passed in (or anything else can happen too).

In your code, matching format specifiers would be: `"%td"` for `pch - str + 1`, `"%s"` for `pch`, and `"%s"` for `str`. Although I'm not clear on what you are hoping to print out on the second line.

Comment: I am hoping to understand what do the `str` and `pch` represent and how this magic `pch-str+1` works. Why these numbers, why precisely this difference and why `+1` there. Also, this code is from [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com), but without second `printf()`.

Comment: @AlexeyVilchansky `pch - str` isn't magic. Subtracting two pointers gives an integer which is the number of elements between those two pointers.   Adding 1 to an integer gives the next biggest integer.  Also you did not ask about this in your question so maybe update your question to ask that.

Comment: `str` is an array of characters and `ptr` is a pointer to a character.  Using `%d` on them causes undefined behaviour as my answer explains

Answer (score 0):

`pch` is the address of the last `s` in the string. `str` is the address of the beginning of the string. `pch-str` is the number of bytes between `str` and `pch`, which is the position of the `s` in the string. You add `1` because you want the result to be 1-based, like normal humans think, rather than 0-based the way computers think (so if `s` is the first character, it will say `found at 1`, not `found at 0`).

As others have said, the reason you're getting strange values when you print `pch` and `str` is because you used the wrong `printf` format operator. You should use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With `%p` it seems to be that `pch` is bigger than `str` and subtraction goes fine. `+1` also is clear now.  I was embarrassed by the `%d` conversion in the first `printf()` statement. As I've understood, the pointer subtraction goes on and than conversion to integer takes place.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this something like the number of the memory cell, where the pointer to the first character lies (in case of str)? If so, why str is bigger than pch?" --> is like asking why your home address is greater than your friend's home address even though you live on the same street.  There are simply addresses.

The +1 in `pch - str + 1` is likely because the author likes to start counting positions in a string from 1.  It is more idiomatic in C to start from 0, thus : `pch - str`.

Use the matching modifier/specifier.

```
char str[] = "This is a sample string";
char * pch;
pch = strrchr(str,'s');

// pointer subtraction results in type `ptrdiff_t`.  Use `t`
printf("Last occurrence of 's' found at %td \n", pch - str);

// Use p and add cast to `void *`
printf("pch number: %p \n str number: %p", (void *) pch, (void *) str);
```